# Python BeautifulSoup scrape nth-type of elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

recently I started to scrape some multiple pages but structure of page is really difficult to scrape. It has a lot of "nth type of" elements which haven't classes for each self. But their parents share same class. I am working with BeautifulSoup and it was great until I saw this awful code...

```
<div class="detail-50">
    <div class="detail-panel-wrap">
        <h3>Contact details</h3>
            Website: <a href="http://www.somewebsitefrompage.com">http://www.somewebsitefrompage.com</a><br />Email: <a href="mailto:somemailfrompage.com">somemailfrompage.com</a><br />Tel: 11111111 111
                    </div>
                        </div>
```

For now it seems ok, but I want to scrape Website, Email and Tel. separately. I tried with many methods such as

```
website = soup.select('div.detail-panel-wrap')[1].text`
```

But isn't working.. Now here comes huge problem when other elements have same class as contact details:

```
<div class="detail-50">
    <div class="detail-panel-wrap">
        <h3>Public address</h3>
            Mr Martin Austin, Some street, Some city, some ZIP
                    </div>
                        </div>
```

This one is for Address, also I need that scraped too. There are many other 'div' names as these two. Does anybody have resolving solution? If someone didn't understood, I can explain it better, sorry for bad explanation..

**UPDATE**
With some selector software I have found out how it should be, but it's difficult in python to write it.. Here is how to find Telephone from page:

```
div#ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cp_content_ctl00_CharityDetails_4_TabContainer1_tpOverview_plContact.detail-panel div.detail-50:nth-of-type(1) div.detail-panel-wrap
```

This one is for Address

```
div#ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cp_content_ctl00_CharityDetails_4_TabContainer1_tpOverview_plContact.detail-panel div.detail-50:nth-of-type(2) div.detail-panel-wrap
```

This one for Website

```
div.detail-50 a:nth-of-type(1)
```

And this one for contact email

```
div.detail-panel-wrap a:nth-of-type(2)
```

Note:
`ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cp_content_ctl00_CharityDetails_4_TabContainer1_tpOverview_plContact`

is parent div class at the top of all of these.

Anybody have an idea how to write those in BS4 Python?

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple *divs* with class *detail-panel-wrap*, you can use the *h3* text to get the ones you want:

```
contact = soup.find("h3", text="Contact details").parent
address = soup.find("h3", text="Public address").parent
```

If we run it on a sample, you can see we get both divs:

```
In [22]: html = """
   ....: <div class="detail-50">
   ....:     <div class="detail-panel-wrap">
   ....:         <h3>Contact details</h3>
   ....:             Website: <a href="http://www.somewebsitefrompage.com">http://www.somewebsitefrompage.com</a><br />Email: <a href="mailto:somemailfrompage.com">somemailfrompage.com</a><br />Tel: 11111111 111
   ....:                     </div>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div class="detail-50">
   ....:         <div class="detail-panel-wrap">
   ....:             <h3>Public address</h3>
   ....:                  Mr Martin Austin, Some street, Some city, some ZIP
   ....:         </div>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div class="detail-panel-wrap">
   ....:     <   h3>foo/h3>
   ....:     </div>
   ....:     <div class="detail-panel-wrap">
   ....:         <h3>bar/h3>
   ....:     </div>
   ....: </div>
   ....:     """

In [23]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [24]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

In [25]: contact = soup.find("h3", text="Contact details").parent

In [26]: address = soup.find("h3", text="Public address").parent

In [27]: print(contact)
<div class="detail-panel-wrap">
<h3>Contact details</h3>
            Website: <a href="http://www.somewebsitefrompage.com">http://www.somewebsitefrompage.com</a><br/>Email: <a href="mailto:somemailfrompage.com">somemailfrompage.com</a><br/>Tel: 11111111 111
                    </div>

In [28]: print(address)
<div class="detail-panel-wrap">
<h3>Public address</h3>
                 Mr Martin Austin, Some street, Some city, some ZIP
        </div>
```

There may be other ways but without seeing the full html structure it is not possible to know.

For your edit, you simply have to use the selectors with *select_one*:

```
 telephone = soup.select_one("#ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cp_content_ctl00_CharityDetails_4_TabContainer1_tpOverview_plContact.detail-panel div.detail-50:nth-of-type(1) div.detail-panel-wrap")            

address = soup.select_one("#ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cp_content_ctl00_CharityDetails_4_TabContainer1_tpOverview_plContact.detail-panel div.detail-50:nth-of-type(2) div.detail-panel-wrap")


website = soup.select_one("div.detail-50 a:nth-of-type(1)")

email = soup.select_one("div.detail-panel-wrap a:nth-of-type(2)")
```

But there is no guarantee just because the selectors work in chrome tools etc.. that they  will work on the source you get back.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, you can see an update I have attached how it should be directly but the problem is with how to write it in python code.

Comment: @Ukii, the selectors you added in your edit seem like something you copied from chrome tools and may not work on the actual source but regardless you literally just have to them exactly as they are in a select